# How to create a Shopping Cart Price rule for free shipping for all items, with some exclusions?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping, rules

I have a clean build of CE 1.9.1.1 and have loaded the sample data provided by Magento. I want to set up a Shopping Cart Price Rule for free shipping on all items except 2 SKUs (one simple SKU and it's parent configurable SKU).

I've created a rule with no conditions (to apply to all products), and in the Actions tab have set the Free Shipping to 'Matching Products only.'

Within the 'Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions' section, I have

`If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
   SKU  is not one of  wbk000c-Pink-L, wbk002c`

But after adding wbk000c-Pink-L to my cart, it is getting free shipping applied.

How do I create a Shopping Cart Price rule for free shipping for all items, but with some exclusions?

Comment: did u solved your issue